# Creating arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am little new to javascript and I am having alittle trouble wrapping my head around making a 2d (or maybe i might need a 3d) array in javascript.

I currently have 2 pieces of information i need to collect: an ID and a value so I created the following:

```
var myArray = [];

var id = 12;
var value = 44;

myArray[id]=value;
```

But I realized that this is not easy to loop through the array like a for loop so i was thinking of this:

```
myArray[myArray.length] = id;
myArray[myArray.length-1][id]=value;
```

I wanted to do this so that in a for loop i could get the ids and the values easily but the above only returns the value when i loop through it. Any suggestions on how to get this working or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do. Are you trying to store a bunch of (id, value) pairs? Do you need to retrieve the value by id at a later time or just iterate through the pairs?

Comment: @takteek iterate through the pairs so I want to access both the value and id at element 0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not use an array of [object hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)es? This approach allows you to store multiple values in a key:value format:

```
var myArray = [];
var myElement = {
  id: 12,
  value: 44
}

myArray[0] = myElement;
```

You could then loop through all of the elements in `myArray` like so:

```
var i = 0,
    el;

while (el = myArray[i++]) {
  alert(el.id + '=' + el.value);
}
```

Comment: id and value are not always 12 and 44, its whatever the user sets the var to unless theres a way to set myElement.id = 0 myElement.value then set array to myElement

Comment: You just described how to do it, haha. `myElement.id = 0`

Comment: @takteek Awesome thanks...I was hoping it would work the same way

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is a dictionary like structure (in JS it's called an object), eg { id => value}

In JS you can do something like this:

```
var myDict = { 'myId' : 'myValue' };
myDict[12] = 44; // from your example and this will be added to myDict
myDict[11] = 54;

for (var key in myDict) {
  console.log('key: ' + key + ', value: ' + myDict[key]);
}​
```

The output will be:

key: 11, value: 54

key: 12, value: 44

key: myId, value: myValue

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do multi-dimensional arrays is creating then on the fly using loops.

so you can have like `array[x][y][z]` like I saw your `3D-array` tag.

To loop trough is not that hard, you can verify the length of the array, when you reach the end of one dimension e.g. `z` increase the `y` by one and reset `z` to 0.

Exemple constructor of 2d-array:

```
function Array2d(x,y){

    var array = new Array(x);

    while(x>0){
        array[x]=new Array(y);
        x--;
    }

    return array;
}
```

to create a 2d array you can use like this:

```
var myMatrix = Array2d(4,4);
```

this is generate a empty 4x4 matrix `myMatrix[4][4]`

```
(0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (3,0)
(0,1) (1,1) (2,1) (3,1)
(0,2) (1,2) (2,2) (3,2)
(0,3) (1,3) (2,3) (3,3)
```

to do a 3D or more dimensions just put other loop inside the loop.

---

note: I not tested this function, this is just a algorithm, you should verify the input, if you insert a negative length or float this is probably crash you browser.