# Splitting sentence into words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am basically trying to split entire input into words and then display it (possibly store it inside variables or an array so I can display it later). So far I made a system to count the words but I have to also split them so I can use them.
Words are separated by space " "

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").on("submit", function (e) {

        var words = $.trim($("#command_text").val()).split(' '); /* Count words*/
        alert(words.length);

        $("#command_text").val('');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: *I made a system to count the words but I have to also split them so I can use them.*    `words` is literally an array of the words from your input....exactly what you're asking for, you even called `.split(' ')` to get the array

Comment: Basically how do I store it inside of an array? Lets say I wrote this
"Hello World"
Now I want to acess the array and var array[0] would hold "Hello" and var array[1] would hold "World" (just an example)

Comment: Again, `words` *is an **array** the words from your input* you already have what you are asking for

Comment: do `alert(words)` or `console.log(words)` to see what we mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating arrays in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543518/creating-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Why would anyone upvote this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code and you will see that you have already stored them into an array as DelightedDOD states.

```
alert(words[0]);
alert(words[1]);
alert(words[2]);
```

Once you have done that, you may want to close the question.

Comment: No problem @TomislavTomiNikolic. Welcome to StackOverflow. It takes a little getting used to but you will find that people will encourage you to look for an existing question that is similar before asking. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = 'JavaScript String split()';
let substrings = str.split(' ');

console.log(substrings);
console.log(substrings[0]);

// o/p : 
// 1) ["JavaScript", "String", "split()"]
// 2) JavaScript
```